# How to call function inside a main function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a function in MATLAB, say `[o1, o2]=MyFunction(i1,i2)`, and I have a main which is also in a function called main. Is this even make sense?

I did it in MATLAB as follow:

```
function main
  i1=1;
  i2=2;
  [o1, o2]=MyFunction(i1, i2);
end 

function [o1, o2]=MyFunction(i1, i2)
   %Code goes here.
end
```

I cannot run this script anyway. Please any suggestions?

Comment: That code runs, as long as you assign values to `o1` and `o2` within the body of `MyFunction`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "main" function in MATLAB. You should move its contents to a separate script, like the following:

Script 1:

```
i1=1;
i2=2;
[o1, o2]=MyFunction(i1, i2);
```

Script 2 (called "MyFunction.m"):

```
function [o1, o2]=MyFunction(i1, i2)
   %Code goes here.
end
```

Then run Script 1.

Answer (score 2):

as it has been commented above it works fine...  also if all you want the function to do is define simple variables and call another function @ClydeW's answer is a sensible way to do that. For more complicated variables mat-files created with `save` or `matfile` and recoverd with `load` or `matfile` are available.

In Matlab terminology what you have there is a [local function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html)

**Local Functions** are extra functions defined within a function m-file, appearing after the `end` of the "main" function.  Local functions have a separate workspace i.e. to use variables from the main function they will need to be inputs to the local function

Other alternatives for having "sub-functions" which are stored in the same m-file and used by the "main" function within Matlab are [Nested Functions](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html) and [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html)

**Nested functions** are similar to a local function but appear within the "main" function definition i.e. before the `end`. The major difference being that a nested function has acces to the main functions workspace i.e. can use & modify variables from the main function without having them explicity as inputs or outputs

**Anonymous functions** are quite different in that they need defining with different syntax again within the "main" function, but prior to use (appearing earlier in file than the call to them).  The inputs to an anonymous function come from the main function however other values used within an anonymous function use values from the main function at the time the anonymous function was defined.